# MVC 5 application view breaks when "certain" images are imbeded

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have searched all over for this issue, so I am putting this question here.   Here is my issue:

I have a MVC 5 web application which allows our administrators to upload the logo files of our clients, who are hosted in this web application.  This logo is displayed on the setup page and also pages that are displayed to our clients "customers".

The issue is that periodically a client will supply us with a file that will break the page, in that it will not display the logo and will not render any part of the page that should have been there after the logo.  We have looked at these problem logos in various photo editors and tried re-saving them, they look fine, until we try to display them on the site.  They are stored in our database and are less than 500kb in size, most are much smaller.

So here is what I have in my cshtml view:

```
<div class="display-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LogoData)</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @{
        if (Model.LogoData != null)
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.LogoData);
            var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);

            <img src="@imgSrc" />
        }
    }
</div>
```

When this is working, the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="display-label">Logo</div>
<div class="display-field">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMIAAAEDCAIAAADoQE..." />
</div>
```

I truncated the image data for the purposes of this code snippet, but you get the idea.

When we get a bad image, the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="display-label">Logo</div>
<div class="display-field">
```

And that's it, there is no more HTML rendered in the page, other than closing body tag, etc.

My working theory here is that there is something in the image data that is causing the razor view engine to biff, but I am at a loss of how to identify it or fix it.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is totally off-topic in relation to your question, but have you thought about storing images on the server or some other storage as files and just saving URLs to those files in database?

Comment: based specifically on the snippet you posted, it suggests that `Model.LogoData` is null. I'd start looking there.

Comment: That actually has crossed my mind, specifically in relation to this issue.  In our case though, working with our admins to open up permissions to the file system on the webapps server... was more than we wanted to deal with at the time.  That said if no other solution can be found, we may take another look.   The thing that naws at me though, is why only certain images cause this behaviour...  I would love to know why.

Comment: Takarii,  is there a reason a null logo data would cause the rest of the elements in the view not to render?  It not just an issue of the image not showing, it actually obliterates the rest of the page, but not in a way that creates broken html, its just missing everything else.  We have looked at the images in the data base, and they are indeed there, there is data.

Comment: I couldn't say im afraid. As for our null data, it could be many reasons, but i would lean towards the data having never been stored in the first place (some uncaught error or exception). If you have examples of "bad data" debug the app with a breakpoint in the code you posted and see if it is indeed null. You could also save yourself some time by passing the "bad data" examples to your admins to check themselves so you dont have to deal with all the access issues

Comment: Just a random idea: try using `<img src="@Html.Raw(imgSrc)" />`. If nothing else it should make things a tiny bit faster, a Base64-string does not need HTML encoding. And who knows what kind of rare bug you may be triggering if you do it anyway, with those huge strings. Also, are you using the latest MVC (5.2.3)?

Comment: Another idea: surround the `if { ... }` with `try {` and `} catch { ... }`, and write something to the page from inside the catch part. A simple `<-- comment -->` would do, or `ex.Message` of course.

Comment: Ok,  couple of things.  On the data being null, I  am 99.9% sure that is not the case.  I can query the database and see the data there after its saved.  That said, I would love to debug it and see whats going on, and that is the frustrating part, it happens in production and our UAT test, two places I cannot debug, but when I take the same image in our test environment..... it works, even when its the same code.

Comment: Ok, separating these comments a bit for clarity, on <img src="@Html.Raw(imgsrc....   I will try that, I am willing to try anything at this point and I like the idea of it being faster, will keep you posted if that works.     MVC version, I apologize, we are actually on 4

Comment: One other thing, I realized this after the last spat of comments, the image being null cannot be the issue, because I am actually checking for that. See code snippet in the post, where I am doing an if (Model.LogoData != null)